# Creating Custom Annotation Using Spring that supports Flexible Method Signature

Tags: java, spring

In Spring MVC, Inside a Controller class, the method annotated with `@RequestMapping` annotation are allowed to have `Flexible Method Signature`.

If I want to do something like this with my own `custom annotation`, Can somebody give me some pointers for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC has a *lot* of features in that regard so it might be easier to look elsewhere as a starting point. The new messaging abstraction that was introduced in Spring 4 has similar features.

Look at `@MessageMapping` which allows you to build a flexible signature against a `Message` instance. You could for instance inject a header of the message

```
public void foo(@Header("myHeader") int myHeader)
```

Or you could validate that the payload against a `Validator`

```
public void bar(@Payload @Validated Order order)
```

The core of the infrastructure is located in `InvocableHandlerMethod` which is going to invoke a `java.lang.reflect.Method` you have provided on a given bean instance based on an incoming `Message` and additional parameters you may provide (see `public final Object invoke(Message<?> message, Object... providedArgs)`

To create that instance, you need to provide a set of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Each `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is responsible to handle a method parameter. In short, that's basically going to provide you a `MethodParameter` instance (i.e. a reference to a parameter of the method you want to handle, such as the annotated `order` in the last example) and you're going to tell if you support it or not and when you do, handle that parameter so that the right value is injected. For the header example, the implementation looks for a header with the name on the annotation. Simple!

A set of default resolvers are created for example in `SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` (look at  `initArgumentResolvers`). That's going to show you the kind of parameters you can inject there by default. By extending that list (or providing custom instances) you can augment what the user can use in the method signature.

In Spring 4.1, we rely on this infrastructure to provide JMS listener annotated endpoints and those endpoints may have a flexible signature as well. It's [actually already implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/config/DefaultJmsHandlerMethodFactory.java) so you may want to have a look to that for yet another example.